DraftJS TypeError: store.getItem(...) is not a function - NextJS
I am using DraftJS Plugins Editor in my NextJS project like below:
const Editor = dynamic(() => import("@draft-js-plugins/editor"), {
  ssr: false,
});

const inlineToolbarPlugin = createInlineToolbarPlugin();
const { InlineToolbar } = inlineToolbarPlugin;

function MyEditor() {
  const [editorState, setEditorState] = useState(EditorState.createEmpty());

  return (
    <div className="editor-container">
      <Editor
        placeholder="Start writing..."
        editorState={editorState}
        onChange={setEditorState}
        plugins={[inlineToolbarPlugin]}
      />
      <InlineToolbar />
    </div>
  );
}

export default MyEditor;

But the app keeps crashing with the below error:
TypeError: store.getItem(...) is not a function

Any idea how to fix this?
